# How to convert Base64 encode binary String to binary in java?

Tags: java, android, salesforce

How can i convert the following Base64 encode binary string into a binary in java. I have seen people doing the same in php using the following code. How to achieve this in java?

In PHP:

```
$byteArr = "AAAAAEAA";
$maparray = array();
$map = "";
foreach(str_split($byteArr) as $c)
    $maparray [] = sprintf("%08b", ord($c));
$map = implode("", $maparray );

Output is $map -> "000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000";
```

But when i try this in java:

```
String input = "AAAAAEAA";
String mapArray = "";
for(int b=0;b<input.length();b++){
   int asciValueOfChar =(int)toByte.charAt(b);
   String binaryInt = Integer.toBinaryString(asciValueOfChar);
   String paddedBinaryInt = String.format("%8s", binaryInt);
   paddedBinaryInt = paddedBinaryInt.replace(' ', '0');
   System.out.println("ASCII Code::"+asciValueOfChar);
   System.out.println("Binary of Char::"+binaryInt);
   System.out.println("Binary of Padded Char::"+binaryInt);
   mapArray = mapArray + paddedBinaryInt ;
}
System.out.println("Binary Array::"+mapArray);

Output is mapArray -> "0100000101000001010000010100000101000001010001010100000101000001"
```

The output varies.

How can i achieve the same output?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't believe PHP gives you above mentioned string (`000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000`) as an output!

The code in your question enumerate each character in input string (`AAAAAEAA`), retrieves [ASCII value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) of each character and post it in output. If you execute PHP code you mentioned, you will give exact the same output, as running JAVA code you mentioned (`0100000101000001010000010100000101000001010001010100000101000001`).

For example,

```
ord("A") = 65
```

65 in turn has `01000001` binary representation.

Second, correct your question to get correct answer. It seems, guys, answered earlier, didn't understand your question at all.

Third, if you want to get binary represenation of a given string, use [getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) method to retrieve bytes representation of entire string. Use or adapt [this code snippet](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Core_Java/code3.html) to get binary representation of a given bytes-array.

Answer (score 1):

To decode base64, the simplest is to use the [Apache commons Decoder](http://commons.apache.org/codec/).

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(input);
```

Do you really need the binary as a string made of "0" and "1" chars ?

Comment: You can also use javax.xml.DatatypeConverter if you wish to limit dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

I expect people to recommend apache commons but I do not know if it's portable or not...

you can use this one:

```
public class Base64Coder
{

// Mapping table from 6-bit nibbles to Base64 characters.
private static final char[] map1                = new char[64];
static
{
    int i = 0;
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        map1[i++] = c;
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        map1[i++] = c;
    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
        map1[i++] = c;
    map1[i++] = '+';
    map1[i++] = '/';
}
// Mapping table from Base64 characters to 6-bit nibbles.
private static final byte[] map2                = new byte[128];
static
{
    for (int i = 0; i < map2.length; i++)
        map2[i] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        map2[map1[i]] = (byte) i;
}
// The line separator string of the operating system.
private static final String systemLineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");


/**
 * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
 * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static byte[] decode(char[] in)
{
    return decode(in, 0, in.length);
}

/**
 * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
 * @param iOff
 *            Offset of the first character in <code>in</code> to be
 *            processed.
 * @param iLen
 *            Number of characters to process in <code>in</code>, starting
 *            at <code>iOff</code>.
 * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static byte[] decode(char[] in, int iOff, int iLen)
{
    if (iLen % 4 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length of Base64 encoded input string is not a multiple of 4.");
    while (iLen > 0 && in[iOff + iLen - 1] == '=')
        iLen--;
    int oLen = (iLen * 3) / 4;
    byte[] out = new byte[oLen];
    int ip = iOff;
    int iEnd = iOff + iLen;
    int op = 0;
    while (ip < iEnd)
    {
        int i0 = in[ip++];
        int i1 = in[ip++];
        int i2 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
        int i3 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
        if (i0 > 127 || i1 > 127 || i2 > 127 || i3 > 127)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
        int b0 = map2[i0];
        int b1 = map2[i1];
        int b2 = map2[i2];
        int b3 = map2[i3];
        if (b0 < 0 || b1 < 0 || b2 < 0 || b3 < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
        int o0 = (b0 << 2) | (b1 >>> 4);
        int o1 = ((b1 & 0xf) << 4) | (b2 >>> 2);
        int o2 = ((b2 & 3) << 6) | b3;
        out[op++] = (byte) o0;
        if (op < oLen) out[op++] = (byte) o1;
        if (op < oLen) out[op++] = (byte) o2;
    }
    return out;
}

/**
 * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            A Base64 String to be decoded.
 * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static byte[] decode(String s)
{
    return decode(s.toCharArray());
}

/**
 * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format and ignores line separators, tabs
 * and blanks. CR, LF, Tab and Space characters are ignored in the input
 * data. This method is compatible with
 * <code>sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.decodeBuffer(String)</code>.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            A Base64 String to be decoded.
 * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static byte[] decodeLines(String s)
{
    char[] buf = new char[s.length()];
    int p = 0;
    for (int ip = 0; ip < s.length(); ip++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(ip);
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\r' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') buf[p++] = c;
    }
    return decode(buf, 0, p);
}

/**
 * Decodes a string from Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are allowed
 * within the Base64 encoded input data.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            A Base64 String to be decoded.
 * @return A String containing the decoded data.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static String decodeString(String s)
{
    return new String(decode(s));
}

/**
 * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * inserted in the output.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
 * @return A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static char[] encode(byte[] in)
{
    return encode(in, 0, in.length);
}

/**
 * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * inserted in the output.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
 * @param iLen
 *            Number of bytes to process in <code>in</code>.
 * @return A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static char[] encode(byte[] in, int iLen)
{
    return encode(in, 0, iLen);
}

/**
 * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * inserted in the output.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
 * @param iOff
 *            Offset of the first byte in <code>in</code> to be processed.
 * @param iLen
 *            Number of bytes to process in <code>in</code>, starting at
 *            <code>iOff</code>.
 * @return A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static char[] encode(byte[] in, int iOff, int iLen)
{
    int oDataLen = (iLen * 4 + 2) / 3;       // output length without padding
    int oLen = ((iLen + 2) / 3) * 4;         // output length including padding
    char[] out = new char[oLen];
    int ip = iOff;
    int iEnd = iOff + iLen;
    int op = 0;
    while (ip < iEnd)
    {
        int i0 = in[ip++] & 0xff;
        int i1 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] & 0xff : 0;
        int i2 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] & 0xff : 0;
        int o0 = i0 >>> 2;
        int o1 = ((i0 & 3) << 4) | (i1 >>> 4);
        int o2 = ((i1 & 0xf) << 2) | (i2 >>> 6);
        int o3 = i2 & 0x3F;
        out[op++] = map1[o0];
        out[op++] = map1[o1];
        out[op] = op < oDataLen ? map1[o2] : '=';
        op++;
        out[op] = op < oDataLen ? map1[o3] : '=';
        op++;
    }
    return out;
}

/**
 * Encodes a byte array into Base 64 format and breaks the output into lines
 * of 76 characters. This method is compatible with
 * <code>sun.misc.BASE64Encoder.encodeBuffer(byte[])</code>.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
 * @return A String containing the Base64 encoded data, broken into lines.
 */
public static String encodeLines(byte[] in)
{
    return encodeLines(in, 0, in.length, 76, systemLineSeparator);
}

/**
 * Encodes a byte array into Base 64 format and breaks the output into
 * lines.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
 * @param iOff
 *            Offset of the first byte in <code>in</code> to be processed.
 * @param iLen
 *            Number of bytes to be processed in <code>in</code>, starting
 *            at <code>iOff</code>.
 * @param lineLen
 *            Line length for the output data. Should be a multiple of 4.
 * @param lineSeparator
 *            The line separator to be used to separate the output lines.
 * @return A String containing the Base64 encoded data, broken into lines.
 */
public static String encodeLines(byte[] in, int iOff, int iLen, int lineLen, String lineSeparator)
{
    int blockLen = (lineLen * 3) / 4;
    if (blockLen <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int lines = (iLen + blockLen - 1) / blockLen;
    int bufLen = ((iLen + 2) / 3) * 4 + lines * lineSeparator.length();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(bufLen);
    int ip = 0;
    while (ip < iLen)
    {
        int l = Math.min(iLen - ip, blockLen);
        buf.append(encode(in, iOff + ip, l));
        buf.append(lineSeparator);
        ip += l;
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

/**
 * Encodes a string into Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
 * inserted.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            A String to be encoded.
 * @return A String containing the Base64 encoded data.
 */
public static String encodeString(String s)
{
    return new String(encode(s.getBytes()));
}

// Dummy constructor.
private Base64Coder()
{
}
}
```

Usage:

```
String message = "blahblah";
byte[] encoded = Base64Coder.encode(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] decoded = Base64Coder.decode(encoded);
String msg2 = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
if(message.equals(msg2)) System.out.println("yaay");
```

It's also compatible with Sun's code...

Answer (score 0):

Android includes its own Base64 encoder and decoder. All you need to decode a Base64 string is this:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode( string, Base64.DEFAULT );
```

The second parameter is a flag. See here: [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)