# Base64 to Binary Conversion using Java

Tags: java, binary, base64

I already went over the responses I found for the question I have posted, but I wasn't able to figure out something. I would really appreciate it if somebody could please articulate on this a little bit:

I was trying to convert a base64 string into binary. I came across the following code, and I have the base64 string stored in a byte array. How can I convert the byte array into binary.
The code I found:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Base64Decode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           String hello = "AAADccwwCBwOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAB==";

           byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(hello.getBytes());

           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decoded));

          }
}
```

**Output:**

> [0, 0, 3, 113, -52, 48, 8, 28, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Is the output correct? When I looked up some documentation for base64 conversion, I noticed the equivalent of "A" is 0. How does the array have a zero in the last slot? Would it not be having the equivalent of "B". Should my array not begin with three 0s then? How can I convert this into binary (in terms of 0s' and 1s')?

Comment: Have you seen this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317518/how-to-convert-base64-encode-binary-string-to-binary-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base 64, each character represents 6 bits of information.
A four-character sequence represents 24 bits of information (i.e 3 bytes).

Then, the sequence `AAAD` represents `{0,0,3}`.

```
   AAAD -> 000000 000000 000000 000011 -> 00000000 00000000 00000011
```

The last sequence `AAB=`, where the final `=` is a padding character, represents a **16-bit** value (there are actually 18 bits, but the last two bits are ignored), equivalent to `{0, 0}`.

```
   AAB= -> 000000 000000 000001 -> 00000000 00000000 (ignored: 01)
```

Had the last sequence been `AB==`, it would have represented an **8-bit** value, equivalent to `{0}`.

```
   AB== -> 000000 000001 -> 00000000 (ignored: 0001)
```

Comment: Hi Javier, Thanks for the explanation. This helps! How do I convert the byte output into binary in Java?

Comment: If you want a string representation of the byte values, do `new BigInteger(1, decoded).toString(2)`

Comment: Thanks Javier!! I looked up the documentation for the BigInteger and understood the line of code. That answer was very helpful!